# Multiple tab click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hi everyone i am trying to make a jquery tab but i want to use it multiple like for example in one page have 100 tab what can i do on that time.

I am trying in this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/KdwOpr)** link. If you click one blue button then you can see the tab. Click the red buttons like *STARKS* button then other tab also doesn't work. Anyone can help me here ?

```
<div class="icon_c">
  <div class="clickficon"></div>
  <div class="emicon-menu MaterialTabs">
    <ul>
      <li class="tab active"><a href="#starks-panel">Starks</a></li>
      <li class="tab"><a href="#lannisters-panel">Lannisters</a></li>
      <li class="tab"><a href="#targaryens-panel">Targaryens</a><span></span></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="panels">
      <div id="starks-panel" class="panel pactive">
        a
      </div>
      <div id="lannisters-panel" class="panel">
        b
      </div>
      <div id="targaryens-panel" class="panel">
        c
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="icon_b">
  <div class="clickficon"></div>
  <div class="emicon-menu MaterialTabs">
    <ul>
      <li class="tab active"><a href="#starks-panel">Starks</a></li>
      <li class="tab"><a href="#lannisters-panel">Lannisters</a></li>
      <li class="tab"><a href="#targaryens-panel">Targaryens</a><span></span></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="panels">
      <div id="starks-panel" class="panel pactive">
        a
      </div>
      <div id="lannisters-panel" class="panel">
        b
      </div>
      <div id="targaryens-panel" class="panel">
        c
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 issues.

The 1st is on the initTabs_ function.
It takes all the .panel divs for both MaterialTabs, it should take only the ones that are childs of the MaterialTabs element.
You should replace:

```
// Select element tabs, document panels
this.tabs_   = this.element_.querySelectorAll('.tab');
this.panels_ = document.querySelectorAll('.panel');
```

For:

```
// Select element tabs, document panels
this.tabs_   = this.element_.querySelectorAll('.tab');
this.panels_ = this.element_.querySelectorAll('.panel');
```

The seccond issue is with the tabs ids and href srcs in both panels references to the same ids, if you change the second panel as follows:

```
<div class="emicon-menu MaterialTabs">
    <ul>
      <li class="tab active"><a href="#starks-panel1">Starks</a></li>
      <li class="tab"><a href="#lannisters-panel1">Lannisters</a></li>
      <li class="tab"><a href="#targaryens-panel1">Targaryens</a><span></span></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="panels">
      <div id="starks-panel1" class="panel pactive">
        a
      </div>
      <div id="lannisters-panel1" class="panel">
        b
      </div>
      <div id="targaryens-panel1" class="panel">
        c
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

It should work independently of the first one.

You can found the code modified [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rOVKPz)

Comment: so can i ask you a one more question ?

Comment: can you check my other question for me ? Please [Click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32464322/facebook-style-emoticonsticker-box-ajax-click-function) for that question

Comment: do you have any idea for solution about that question ?